# Troubles with a cell size of a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I have a cell of UICollectionView with size

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
     return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width / 2 - 10,height: self.view.frame.width / 2 - 10)
```

[image]

[image]

But at the run time

[image]

Storyboard

[image]

New!

After scroll the view is fine

[image]

Start of array
Views before scroll

[image]

End of array

[image]

Again start of array 
Views after scroll

[image]

Thanks.
What is wrong with my cell ?

Comment: Have you set `delegate` for it?

Comment: Yes 
`self.collectionView.delegate = self`
`self.collectionView.dataSource = self`

Comment: Could you take a screen shot of your storyboard.

Comment: I thought your cell size is correct, the problem here is your cell's content. Just try to clear content's constraints and add it again.